# Why does Ocaml throw this "expression was expected of type int" error only when a function is applied on negative integers

Tags: ocaml, typing

Let me explain what I'm trying to do first. I'm learning about Ocaml types, and I define a new type, say `int2` that is the same as `int`.

```
# type int2 = int;;
type int2 = int
```

So far so good.

Now I want to define a function called `add_five` that take an argument of type `int` and returns a value of type `int2`

```
# let add_five (x : int) = (x + 5 : int2);;
val add_five : int -> int2 = <fun>
```

Great! Now I want to apply this to one positive number, and one negative number to confirm that it works correctly.

```
# add_five 5;;
- : int2 = 10
```

That worked correctly!

```
# add_five -7;;
Error: This expression has type int -> int2
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

What? I don't understand why this is happening. I explicitly told Ocaml I wanted a return function of type `int2`, so why is it claiming it needed to be type `int`?

Comment: You need parens around `-7`: `add_five (-7)`. There are lots of answers here which explain why.

Comment: As a side comment, `type int2 = int` doesn't define a new type. It just defines a synonym. After this definition, `int2` and `int` are two names for the same type.

Answer (score 4):

`add_five -7` is parsed as `(add_five) - (7)`, i.e., the `-` operator is infix. So `add_five` is expected to be something from which you can subtract `7`, i.e., a value of type `int`. The solution is either to parenthesize it `(-7)` or use the infix form of the negation `~-7`